# transform element inside grid layout does not work CSS

Tags: html, css, 3d, transform

The following is my HTML and CSS Code. I dont know why transform inside the selector "section > .back" does not work. I think it could be, because of the grid or position absolute, but I could not solve the problem.

--cube-length: 300px
--cube-half-length: 150px
--cube-pieces-length: 100px

This is not working:

```css
#perspective {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: 800px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#perspective > div {
    height: var(--cube-length);
    width: var(--cube-length);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#perspective > .front {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 
      "top-left top-center top-right"
      "middle-left middle-center middle-right"
      "bottom-left bottom-center bottom-right";
}

#perspective > .front {
    transform: translateZ(var(--cube-half-length));
    background-color: blue;
}

section {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    grid-area: top-left;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

section > div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

section > .back {
    transform: translateZ(calc(var(--cube-pieces-length)*-2));
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div id="perspective">
            <div class="front">
                <section>
                    <div class="back"></div>
                    <div class="front"></div>
                    <div class="top"></div>
                    <div class="bottom"></div>
                    <div class="left"></div>
                    <div class="right"></div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you make sure your snippet shows the problem? At the moment it shows nothing - and when I add in those CSS variables I'm not certain what it is I am supposed to see.